# Is there any way to use python list as reference of original object even with "=" sign?

Tags: python, list, reference

I hope to achieve the following function with list:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
l = []
l.append(a)
l.append(b)
l.append(c)
```

and if I do:

```
l[0] = 4
```

I hope I could get

```
l = [4, 2, 3]
```

as well as

```
a = 4
```

The difference between this question and many other similar questions is that, I hope to find a way to achieve this with `=` sign, which in most cases will mean to ask the list set its pointer to another object instead of giving the right hand side value to its current pointing one.

Comment: There are no pointers in Python. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: It's not possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `a=4` points to the integer value 4, which is immutable in python. You cannot change it. You can only change the value of mutable objects, like lists, sets, and dictionaries, plus custom made objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do something like:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [2]
>>> c = [3]
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(a)
>>> l.append(b)
>>> l.append(c)
>>> l
[[1], [2], [3]]

>>> l[0][0] = 4 
>>> a
[4]
>>> l
[[4], [2], [3]]
>>>
```

Since `l[0] = 4` will create a new object, not change `a`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know if `a` is a `list` or a `dic` it could be done with their own ways. I just hope to find a way to do this when `a` is an integer.

Comment: @HaohanWang: However as far as I know, that's impossible as the other answer and the comments say.